# mouseover on span to make visible using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website that has a large panel. This panel created by an span in the code with class name="_nb8H _BdWj" on it so when i moves my mouse over it the menu will be showing.
I need JavaScript code to Keep this span open Just like when my mouseover it then i can Simulator click to one that options.

when the span will be visible i had this this class name inside executed codes but when i leave my mouse it disappears

```
document.getElementsByClassName("_nb8H _BdWj")[0].click();
```

I read some code about "event dispatch" but I did not understand.

Comment: How is this related to HTML?

Comment: I think not. I corrected the question.

Comment: No problem, just making sure :D Be sure to check out [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)